# 200amp to sub panel 150amp with 3 #2 ag do I need a 4TH

Tags: electrical-panel

Built tiny house and put in 200amp meter outside box with 20 spaces and lugs at bottom. I'm going to run single 3 # 2 AWG wires to run 150amp. Do I need a 4TH wire? I ran gray pipe under house to box.

Comment: TL;DR Yes, any new installation needs hot/hot/neutral/ground = 4 wires. But there are a bunch of other issues. Is this the only thing on the meter? If not, max. for 2 AWG is 115A copper or 90A aluminum. If it is the only thing then you get service derate, which I believe is 83% - still not nearly 150A.

Comment: Do you want 150 amps at the sub panel or are you just using a 150 amp max panel?

Comment: Yeah, it'd be nice to hear your NEC 220.82 Load Calculation for the tiny house. 150A is a lot for a tiny house, equipment that uses 120A will emit 100,000 BTUs, that's a blistering amount of heat, you'd be smoked out of the place for sure! My winter cottage's main furnace is 50k BTU and it's not a tiny house.

Comment: Maybe it's a tiny smoke house?

Answer (score 4):

I can tell right now that's not gonna work, and is the costly way to do it anyway.

It's your money, but using copper wire for heavy feeder is a waste of it.  Aluminum is proven safe in *large* sizes (15-20A circuits not so much, but now we know what went wrong).  You'll be landing on lugs made of aluminum, so "dissimilar metals" is nonsense. Only reason to go copper is if aluminum won't fit in the conduit. (Been there, paid for that. Ouch.)

So first, to answer your direct question, you need a 4th wire. For 150A service the ground wire must be #6 copper or #4 insulated alumium.   Now there is exactly one exception, and that's if the switch out at the pole is ONLY a disconnect switch or ONLY a single breaker with no possibility of other breakers there.  Then, it can be labeled "NOT SERVICE EQUIPMENT" and 3-wire is fine from there, in fact you get a few other benefits. Hold that thought.

**2 AWG wires are inadequate for 150 amp**.  #2 copper provides only 115A in your application.  #2 aluminum gives only 90A in your application.   For 150A you'll need either 1/0 AWG copper or 3/0 AWG aluminum.

Now, if you are able to have a single disconnect/breaker out at the pole, using that "NOT SERVICE EQUIPMENT" loophole, then #2 copper gives 125A and #2 aluminum gives 100A.  If you really need 150A, #1 copper or 2/0 aluminum will suffice.

Note that gray PVC conduit needs to be trenched for 18" *of cover* over top of the pipe.

Comment: Is the #6 copper or #4 AL a typo or is there special sizes for service feeders?

Comment: @crip659 it's from 250.122. https://up.codes/s/size-of-equipment-grounding-conductors.

Comment: I missed for grounding conductors.  My mistake.